# How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary of points, say:

```
>>> points={'a':(3,4), 'b':(1,2), 'c':(5,5), 'd':(3,3)}
```

I want to create a new dictionary with all the points whose x and y value is smaller than 5, i.e. points 'a', 'b' and 'd'.

According to the [the book](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), each dictionary has the `items()` function, which returns a list of `(key, pair)`  tuple:

```
>>> points.items()
[('a', (3, 4)), ('c', (5, 5)), ('b', (1, 2)), ('d', (3, 3))]
```

So I have written this:

```
>>> for item in [i for i in points.items() if i[1][0]<5 and i[1][1]<5]:
...     points_small[item[0]]=item[1]
...
>>> points_small
{'a': (3, 4), 'b': (1, 2), 'd': (3, 3)}
```

Is there a more elegant way? I was expecting Python to have some super-awesome `dictionary.filter(f)` function...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420122/filter-dict-to-contain-only-certain-keys

Answer (score 568, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
{k: v for k, v in points.items() if v[0] < 5 and v[1] < 5}
```

And in Python 2, starting from 2.7:

```
{k: v for k, v in points.iteritems() if v[0] < 5 and v[1] < 5}
```

Comment: Upvote! This is more than two times faster than Martellis more general approach. Note that you can use views as well (like iteitems, they are NOT a copy of the dict items): {k: v for k, v in points.viewitems() if v[0] < 5 and v[1] < 5}

Comment: And here is a good explanation why the function call dict() is slower than the constructor/literal syntax {} http://doughellmann.com/2012/11/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2.html

Comment: Keep in mind that `iteritems` was removed in Python 3. But you can use `items` instead. It behaves the way `iteritems` works in older versions.

Comment: Hey buddy, I know this is old, but could one use dict comprehension to run partial string matches in 'column x' against dict keys?

Comment: @Datanovice I'm sure one could. One could also open a new question with sufficient detail to get a more useful answer ;)

Comment: One has opened a question with limited responses, thus one has resorted to reading as many questions as one can to gain a better understanding. One saw a more knowledgeable one and thus, continued to pick ones brains ;)

my Q : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50104127/partial-string-match-with-str-contains-using-dict-comprehension-with-python-pand/50104215?noredirect=1#comment87251610_50104215

Comment: As a side note, if someone wanted to determine what was `==` to, it would look like this for the example: `{k: v for k, v in points.items() if v[0] == 5}`

Answer (score 120):

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in points.items() if all(x < 5 for x in v))
```

You could choose to call `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()` if you're in Python 2 and `points` may have a **lot** of entries.

`all(x < 5 for x in v)` may be overkill if you know for sure each point will always be 2D only (in that case you might express the same constraint with an `and`) but it will work fine;-).

Answer (score 27):

```
points_small = dict(filter(lambda (a,(b,c)): b<5 and c < 5, points.items()))
```

Comment: In Python 2 use iteritems() instead of items()

Comment: In python 3.5, this returns an error:

    points_small = dict(filter(lambda (a,(b,c)): b<5 and c < 5, points.items()))
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: I think it's not supported in python 3

Answer (score 25):

```
>>> points = {'a': (3, 4), 'c': (5, 5), 'b': (1, 2), 'd': (3, 3)}
>>> dict(filter(lambda x: (x[1][0], x[1][1]) < (5, 5), points.items()))

{'a': (3, 4), 'b': (1, 2), 'd': (3, 3)}
```

Comment: great ! worth mentioning that this is Py3, as the lambda can no longer unpack the tuple argument (see [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/))

Comment: You compare tuples lexicographically, which is not what OP required. In your case, point `(3, 10)` will pass the test: `(3, 10) < (5, 5)` is True, but it's wrong (`y` should be smaller than 5 as well).

Answer (score 10):

```
dict((k, v) for (k, v) in points.iteritems() if v[0] < 5 and v[1] < 5)
```

Answer (score 9):

I think that Alex Martelli's answer is definitely the most elegant way to do this, but just wanted to add a way to satisfy your want for a super awesome `dictionary.filter(f)` method in a Pythonic sort of way:

```
class FilterDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        for key, value in input_dict.iteritems():
            self[key] = value
    def filter(self, criteria):
        for key, value in self.items():
            if (criteria(value)):
                self.pop(key)

my_dict = FilterDict( {'a':(3,4), 'b':(1,2), 'c':(5,5), 'd':(3,3)} )
my_dict.filter(lambda x: x[0] < 5 and x[1] < 5)
```

Basically we create a class that inherits from `dict`, but adds the filter method. We do need to use `.items()` for the the filtering, since using `.iteritems()` while destructively iterating will raise exception.

Comment: +1 Thanks, elegant code. I really think it should be a part of the standard dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

```
dict((k, v) for (k, v) in points.iteritems() if v[0] < 5 and v[1] < 5)
```