# How to filter a dict to contain only keys in a given list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

Both very new to Python and stackoverflow. Thank you for your patience, and your help.

I would like to filter a dict according to the content of a list like this:

```
d={'d1':1, 'd2':2, 'd3':3}

f = ['d1', 'd3']

r = {items of d where the key is in f}
```

Is this absurd?
If not, what would be the right syntax?

Thank you for your help.

Vincent

Comment: can you assume that the elements are all there?

Comment: What is the desired result if f is `['d1', 'd3', 'd99']`?

Comment: Superset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/python-filter-a-dictionary

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you want to create a new dictionary (for whatever reason):

```
d = {'d1':1, 'd2':2, 'd3':3}
keys = ['d1', 'd3']

filtered_d = dict((k, d[k]) for k in keys if k in d)
# or: filtered_d = dict((k, d[k]) for k in keys)
# if every key in the list exists in the dictionary
```

Comment: dict comprehension syntax? python 2.7 and 3.x -- much neater!

Comment: @Felix Kling I tried this for a dict `d` which has lists in place of values and it returned a void dict. How to amend these few lines accordingly?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani: It shouldn't matter which values the dictionary has: http://codepad.org/PyIJrdJF

Comment: would you deem this faster than:
`for k in keys:
    filtered_d[k]=d[k]` ?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani: Don't know. Time it and see for yourself :)

Comment: `filtered_d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in d}` -- for those looking for a dict comprehesion (dictcomp)

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over the list with a list comprehension and look up the keys in the dictionary, e.g.

```
aa = [d[k] for k in f]
```

Here's an example of it working.

```
>>> d = {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2, 'k3' :3}
>>> f = ['k1', 'k2']
>>> aa = [d[k] for k in f]
>>> aa
[1, 2]
```

If you want to reconstruct a dictionary from the result, you can capture the keys as well in a list of tuples and convert to a dict, e.g.

```
aa = dict ([(k, d[k]) for k in f])
```

More recent versions of Python (specifically 2.7, 3) have a feature called a dict comprehension, which will do it all in one hit.  Discussed in more depth [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)

Comment: Pretty similar, and perfect for me as I don't need checking the existence of the key. Thank you so much.

Comment: Assumes all elements of f are in d.

Comment: Yes, it would break if something wasn't present in the dictionary.  One of the comments on the other post shows a way around that using `d.get(key)`.