# filter items in a python dictionary where keys contain a specific string

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, filtering

I'm a C coder developing something in python. I know how to do the following in C (and hence in C-like logic applied to python), but I'm wondering what the 'Python' way of doing it is.

I have a dictionary d, and I'd like to operate on a subset of the items, only those whose key (string) contains a specific substring.

i.e. the C logic would be:

```
for key in d:
    if filter_string in key:
        # do something
    else
        # do nothing, continue
```

I'm imagining the python version would be something like

```
filtered_dict = crazy_python_syntax(d, substring)
for key,value in filtered_dict.iteritems():
    # do something
```

I've found a lot of posts on here regarding filtering dictionaries, but couldn't find one which involved exactly this.

My dictionary is not nested and i'm using python 2.7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/python-filter-a-dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

Answer (score 264, accepted):

How about a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
filtered_dict = {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if filter_string in k}
```

One you see it, it should be self-explanatory, as it reads like English pretty well.

This syntax requires Python 2.7 or greater.

In Python 3, there is only [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), not `iteritems()` so you would use:

```
filtered_dict = {k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if filter_string in k}
```

Comment: Why not `filtered_dict = {k:d[k] for k in d if filter_string in k}`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm going to *guess* that mine is faster, as it doesn't incurrent the `d[k]` lookup.

Comment: Also, he says `# do something` in the comments, but we drop few keys here.

Comment: Do we have `iteritems` in Python 3? I don't think so. So, my version would be compatible, no?

Comment: In Python 3 you would replace `iteritems` with `items`, which is the same as Python 2.7's `iteritems`.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the built-in [`filter` function](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) to filter dictionaries, lists, etc. based on specific conditions.

```py
filtered_dict = dict(
    filter(lambda item: filter_str in item[0], d.items())
)
```

The advantage is that you can use it for different data structures.

Answer (score 21):

Go for whatever is most readable and easily maintainable. Just because you can write it out in a single line doesn't mean that you should. Your existing solution is close to what I would use other than I would user iteritems to skip the value lookup, and I hate nested ifs if I can avoid them:

```
for key, val in d.iteritems():
    if filter_string not in key:
        continue
    # do something
```

However if you realllly want something to let you iterate through a filtered dict then I would not do the two step process of building the filtered dict and then iterating through it, but instead use a generator, because what is more pythonic (and awesome) than a generator?

First we create our generator, and good design dictates that we make it abstract enough to be reusable:

```
# The implementation of my generator may look vaguely familiar, no?
def filter_dict(d, filter_string):
    for key, val in d.iteritems():
        if filter_string not in key:
            continue
        yield key, val
```

And then we can use the generator to solve your problem nice and cleanly with simple, understandable code:

```
for key, val in filter_dict(d, some_string):
    # do something
```

In short: generators are awesome.

Answer (score 10):

```
input = {"A":"a", "B":"b", "C":"c"}
output = {k:v for (k,v) in input.items() if key_satifies_condition(k)}
```

Comment: My method using `iteritems()` is going to be more efficient than `items()`.

Comment: @Jonathin Reinhart I didn't knew about it. Thanks.

Comment: On Python 2.7 only. In Python 3 there is *only* `items()`, which acts like Python 2.7's `iteritems`.

Comment: The question is explicitly for python 2.7

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built-in function 'filter()':

```
data = {'aaa':12, 'bbb':23, 'ccc':8, 'ddd':34}

# filter by key
print(dict(filter(lambda e:e[0]=='bbb', data.items() ) ) )

# filter by value
print(dict(filter(lambda e:e[1]>18, data.items() ) ) )
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'bbb':23}

{'bbb':23, 'ddd':34}
```

Answer (score 7):

Jonathon gave you an approach using dict comprehensions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862438/790387). Here is an approach that deals with your *do something* part.

If you want to do something with the values of the dictionary, you don't need a dictionary comprehension at all:

*I'm using `iteritems(`) since you tagged your question with [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7)*

```
results = map(some_function, [(k,v) for k,v in a_dict.iteritems() if 'foo' in k])
```

Now the result will be in a list with `some_function` applied to each key/value pair of the dictionary, that has `foo` in its key.

If you just want to deal with the values and ignore the keys, just change the list comprehension:

```
results = map(some_function, [v for k,v in a_dict.iteritems() if 'foo' in k])
```

`some_function` can be any callable, so a lambda would work as well:

```
results = map(lambda x: x*2, [v for k,v in a_dict.iteritems() if 'foo' in k])
```

The inner list is actually not required, as you can pass a *generator expression* to map as well:

```
>>> map(lambda a: a[0]*a[1], ((k,v) for k,v in {2:2, 3:2}.iteritems() if k == 2))
[4]
```

Comment: interesting. how would the some_function be defined? in the first case (k,v), does it just take two parameters? first key then value?

Comment: Yes, just a callable. So `map(lambda a: a[0]*a[1], ((k,v) for k,v in {2:2, 3:2}.iteritems() if k == 2))` - this will give you `[4]`.

Comment: This is correct, but more pythonic than using `map` is a list comprehension. `[f(v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if substring in k]` I think it is much more readable, and more efficient.

Comment: @memo It wouldn't take two parameters, it would take a single parameter with two elements. There is also [starmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) which will unpack into two arguments, however it is a lazy iterator (must be iterated before it executes, i.e. `results = list(starmap(...))` or `for result in starmap(...): ...`).