# python 2.7 : remove a key from a dictionary by part of key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a python dictionary , the dictionary key composed from tupples,

like this :

```
{
 (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Me'): 300, 
 (u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301, 
 (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Key'): 301,
}
```

I'd like to remove all keys from dictionary when only part of tupple appears in key :

for example `'Remove_'`

In this case , must pop two keys: one contains `u'Remove_Me'` and another contains `u'Remove_Key'`

Finally the dictionary will look like this :

```
{
  (u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: what about `u'Do_Don't_Remove_Me'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter items in a python dictionary where keys contain a specific string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862406/filter-items-in-a-python-dictionary-where-keys-contain-a-specific-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
    >>> d = {
     (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Me'): 300, 
     (u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301, 
     (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Key'): 301,
    }
    >>> 
    >>> 
    >>> d_out = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if not any(x.startswith('Remove_') for x in k)}
    >>> d_out
{(u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301}
```

EDIT: In case you wanted to check if `Remove_` is part of any item of the tuple key, then you are better with:

```
>>> d_out = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if not any('Remove_' in x for x in k)}
```

Comment: or `{i:j for i,j in d.items() if not any('Remove_' in x for x in i)}`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj for the head's up

Comment: Don’t use this if there may be elements `DontRemove_Me` inside the key ;)

Comment: @poke op says "only part of the tuple appears in key", not about startswith.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That could refer to the string being anywhere within the tuple key, or that substring being anywhere within a particular string. Not completely clear, so it’s probably best to just mention the impact of one solution over another :)

Comment: I would like to know why this has been down voted...please comment

Answer (score 5):

Since keys are always a combined thing without any structure or pattern, you always need to have the full key in order to access elements in the dictionary. In particular this means that you cannot find elements using some partial key. So in order to do this, there is no way other than looking at all keys:

```
>>> d = {
 (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Me'): 300, 
 (u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301, 
 (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Key'): 301}
>>> { k: v for k, v in d.items() if not any(x.startswith('Remove_') for x in k) }
{(u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301}
```

This will create a new dictionary from the source dictionary, taking every key `k` for which `any(x.startswith('Remove_') for x in k)` is not true. That `any()` expression will be true if there is an element in `x` that starts with `'Remove_'`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same dictionnary, not a one-liner though. Also note that original post said "part of tupple appears in key" so it hasn't to be in the beginning i.e `startswith()`

```
>>> d = {
...      (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Me'): 300, 
...      (u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301, 
...      (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Key'): 301,
...     }
>>> for k in d.keys():
...     for i in k:
...         if 'Remove_' in i:
...             del d[k]
...             break
... 
>>> d
{(u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301}
```

Answer (score 2):

if it is `sartswith` you have already got your answer. If not  then you could use `in` or `re for more complex checking`

**Code:**

```
import re
dic = {
 (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Me'): 300, 
 (u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301, 
 (u'A_String_0', u'A_String_1', u'B_String_3', u'Remove_Key'): 301,
}
print {k:v for k,v in dic.items() if not any(re.match("Remove", val)for val in k)} # Using in
print {k:v for k,v in dic.items() if not any("Remove" in val for val in k)} # Using re.match
```

**Output:**

```
{(u'A_String_0', u'B_String_4'): 301}
```

**Note:**

- This would remover the key if `Remove` occurs any where in the key