# How to extract from dictionaries to only print certain variables python

Tags: python

I had a tsv file like such

```
Name    School   Course         
Nicole  UVA      Biology
Jenna   GWU      CS
```

from there, 
I only want to print the Name and the Course from that dictionary. How would I go about this?

The code below is how I put the original TSV file into the dictionary above.

```
import csv
data = csv.reader(open('data.tsv'),delimiter='\t')
fields = data.next()
for row in data:
    item = dict(zip(fields, row))
    print item
```

So now I got  a dictionary like such:

```
{'Name':'Nicole.', 'School':'UVA.','Course':'Biology'}
{'Name':'Jenna.', 'School':'GWU','Course':'CS'}
{'Name':'Shan', 'School':'Columbia','Course':'Astronomy'}
{'Name':'BILL', 'School':'UMD.','Course':'Algebra'}
```

I only want to print the Name and the Course from that dictionary. How would I go about this?

I want to add code so that I'm only printing

```
{'Name':'Jenna.','Course':'CS'}
{'Name':'Shan','Course':'Astronomy'}
{'Name':'BILL','Course':'Algebra'}
```

Please guide. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the key in the loop

```
for row in data:
    item = dict(zip(fields, row))
    del item['School']
    print item
```

Comment: for this one, can you had other variables in the del item? like can i do del item['School','Name'] because I tried that and it's not letting me.

Comment: you would do: `del item['School']` `del item['Name']` on separate lines

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just remove the `item['School']` entry before printing

```
for row in data:
    item = dict(zip(fields, row))
    del item['School']
    print item
```

But this only works if you know exactly what the dictionary looks like, it has no other entries that you don't want, and it already has a `School` entry.  I would instead recommend that you build a new dictionary out of the old one, only keeping the `Name` and `Course` entries

```
for row in data:
    item = dict(zip(fields, row))
    item = {k, v for k, v in item.items() if k in ('Name', 'Course')}
    print item
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a `DictReader` in the first place, and rebuild the row-dict only if key matches a pre-defined list:

```
import csv

keep = {"Name","Course"}
data = csv.DictReader(open('data.tsv'),delimiter='\t')

for row in data:
    row = {k:v for k,v in row.items() if k in keep}
    print(row)
```

result:

```
{'Course': 'Biology', 'Name': 'Nicole'}
{'Course': 'CS', 'Name': 'Jenna'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer here:
[filter items in a python dictionary where keys contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862406/filter-items-in-a-python-dictionary-where-keys-contain-a-specific-string)

```
print {k:v for k,v in item.iteritems() if "Name" in k or "Course" in k}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using a library designed for these kinds of tasks (Pandas). A dictionary is great for storing key-value pairs, but it looks like you have spreadsheet-like tabular data, so you should choose a storage type that better reflects the data at hand. You could simply do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', sep = '\t')

print df[['Name','Course']]
```

You'll find that as you start doing more complicated tasks, it's better to use well written libraries than to cludge something together

Answer (score 0):

replace the your " print(item) " line with the below line.

```
print(dict(filter(lambda e: e[0]!='School', item)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'Name':'Jenna.','Course':'CS'}
{'Name':'Shan','Course':'Astronomy'}
{'Name':'BILL','Course':'Algebra'}
```