# Filtering defaultdict with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, defaultdict, dictionary-comprehension

I have a defaultdict where keys are a number and values are lists with two entries each.  I want to filter by a condition based on the first entry.  I tried using the suggestion here:  [filter items in a python dictionary where keys contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862406/filter-items-in-a-python-dictionary-where-keys-contain-a-specific-string)

Here is the code I used:

```
circuits = {k:v for k,v in circuits.iteritems() if (v[0]+weightlimit <= histotal) in k}
```

After this code ran, I got an error about a missing key in the only spot in my code where I use the dictionary.

This of course means something is wrong, because a defaultdict does not do that.  So it seems that the dictionary comprehension will change the defaultdict to a dictionary.

What is the best course of action here?  Is it more efficient to use a different method of filtering, or is it more efficient to somehow cast my dictionary to defaultdict?  And what's a good way of doing either?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post example input and desired output?

Comment: Please do not post links to code. Post code as formatted text in the question itself. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dict comprehension produces just that—a dict. Because you filtered, it's a dict now—not a defaultdict. You'll need to wrap it in a `defaultdict` if you want that behavior.

Unless there's a strong need for performance in this block, just stick to that approach. It's cleanest. But [don't prematurely optimize](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Profile your code and speed up the slow  parts.