# Filter dictionary from array values

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary which has values as follows:

```
dictionary = {(10,9): 1, (44,11): 2, (1,1): 99}
```

Basically my keys are pairs of integers and the values of each key are just integers.

I have an array which stores a set of keys:

```
array = [(1,1), (5,19), (58,7)]
```

I would like to filter my dictionary to contain only elements which keys are stored in the array. In my case, after filtering the dictionary I would obtain the following:

```
dictionary = {(1,1): 99}
```

since the only key of the dictionary which is stored in the array is `(1,1)`

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter items in a python dictionary where keys contain a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23862406/filter-items-in-a-python-dictionary-where-keys-contain-a-specific-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
dictionary = {(10,9): 1, (44,11): 2, (1,1): 99}
array = [(1,1), (5,19), (58,7)]

result = { k:v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k in array}
```

**Output**

```
{(1, 1): 99}
```

Or even faster, transforming the list into a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
s = set(array)
result = {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k in s}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could find the set intersection of the dictionary keys and the array tuples, then get your new values in a dict comprehension. This will reduce the complexity of searching for each key in your array:

```
dictionary = {(10,9): 1, (44,11): 2, (1,1): 99}
array = [(1,1), (5,19), (58,7)]

>>> {i:dictionary[i] for i in set(dictionary.keys()).intersection(array)}
{(1, 1): 99}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dict-comprehension:

```
>>> dictionary = {(10,9): 1, (44,11): 2, (1,1): 99}
>>> lst = [(1,1), (5,19), (58,7)]    
>>> d = {k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k in lst}
>>> {(1, 1): 99}
```

I renamed `array` to `lst` because it is a `list`. We should not confuse lists with `numpy` arrays, `array.array` or the `bytearray` type.

You could also write a traditional `for` loop if you are not yet comfortable with comprehensions:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for key in dictionary:
...:    if key in lst:
...:        d[key] = dictionary[key]
...:        
>>> d
>>> {(1, 1): 99}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
res = {i: dictionary[i] for i in array if i in dictionary}
```

This does it in *O(n)* where *n* is the number of items in `array` and doesn't require any additional data structures.

For your `dictionary` and `array`, this gives us:

```
{(1, 1): 99}
```