# How to fetching a list from a list of list if any element matches in the internal list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to fetch the inner list from **'list1'** when the second colomn element of **'list1'** matches with the element coming in loop of **'list2'**

I have a list like this:

```
list1=
    [
        [1546,'token1',12,442],
        [23,'token2',4,542],
        [6,'token3',34,462],
        [336,'token4',45,642],
        [146,'token5',43,62],
    ]
```

and another list :

```
list2=['token1','token2','token3','token4','token5']



 for element in list2:
```

Here I want if **element** == **list1 second colomn element** (i.e. 'token1'==list1's second colomn element 'token1')
then I get the list
        **[ID,element,value1,value2]** (ie **[1546,'token1',12,442]**) from **list1**.

Comment: Looks like you are wanting to filter the list. Take a look at this answer to see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23862438/2793683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```
dict_from_list_1 = {e[1]: e for e in list1}
for element in list2:
    if element in dict_from_list_1:
        print(dict_from_list_1[element])
```

Comment: Second soluiton cannot work with this list correctly while the first one will.

**list2=['token4','token2','token3']**

Comment: if you want to save some memory, in first exemple you could save in  the dict as value the position of your list in list1

Comment: You have given three answer. First one is fine.

Second one time complexity is more.

Third one is not correct.

@rusu_ro1

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is a really simple and powerful way of doing so:

```
lista = [[i for i in list1 if token in i] for token in list2]

print([each[0] for each in lista if len(each)])
```

Output:

```
[[1546, 'token1', 12, 442], [23, 'token2', 4, 542], [6, 'token3', 34,462], [336, 'token4', 45, 642], [146, 'token5', 43, 62]]
```

Comment: I agree, but you shouldn’t overuse it to create hard to read code;)

Comment: I would use the iterator `lista = (...)`. But my solution has a better time complexity:)

Comment: Thanks @HelenaMartins, As I have told earlier I do not want two for loop in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict for lookup using a dictcomp and fetch data into the list using a listcomp:

```
d = {i[1]: i for i in list1}
l = [d[i] for i in list2]
```

Comment: This one is fine.

Answer (score 0):

These are two ways of doing this that will produce the result you want. Let me show the long way:

```
for i in list1:
    if i[1] in list2:
        print (i)
```

Then here we can use a Generator to achieve the above in one line.

```
[element for element in list1 if element[1] in list2]
```

Hope this helps.