# Removing empty dictionary elements in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, empty-list

My program would scrape some website and create two lists, one for category, the other for content. I then use `dict(zip(......))` command to match them and put them into a dict.

Something like this:

```
complete_dict=dict(zip(category_list,info_list))
```

I run into the problem that my program is reading empty element in both lists (category, info). It's fine as long as I can remove them later. The problem is, I failed to find a way to do so. When reading out, both lists contain empty elements, not empty strings, but more like an empty list within a list. I try to remove them both in lists and in dictionary after zipping them, using commands like:

```
category_list=filter(None, category_list)
```

or:

```
info_list=[x for x in info_list if x != []]
```

Of course operation is done for both lists.

None prevailed. I then tried doing it in the dictionary with:

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in complete_list.iteritems() if v)
```

What else can I try at this point?

### Edit

I tried filtering, and either my conditions are not set correctly or it simply doesn't solve the problem. I'm looking for other way so it's not a duplicate of another thread (that thread has some useful info though).

### Edit 2

What I'm getting right now is:

```
[u'info1', u'info2', u'info3', u'info4', ...]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[u'info1', u'info2', u'info3', u'info4', ...]

[]

[]

[]

[u'info1', u'info2', u'info3', u'info4', ...]
```

info 1, 2, 3, and 4 (and there are actually more elements) are content scraped from website, sorry I can't really reveal what those are, but the idea shows. This is one of the list (info_list), and I'm trying to remove all the []'s stuck in middle, so the result should be like

```
[u'info1', u'info2', u'info3', u'info4', ...]

[u'info1', u'info2', u'info3', u'info4', ...]

[u'info1', u'info2', u'info3', u'info4', ...]
```

and so on

### Edit 3

My result looks like this after dict(zip(...))

```
{u'category1': u'info1', u'category2': u'info2', ...}

{}

{}

{u'category1': u'info1', u'category2': u'info2', ...}

{u'category1': u'info1', u'category2': u'info2', ...}

{}

{}

{}
```

and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Filter a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/python-filter-a-dictionary)

Comment: Please show expected input and output. This is still vague to me with the way you've described it.

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with individual empty keys or values. It looks like you're running this comprehension over and over, and sometimes, it produces a completely empty dict. It's probably a problem with the surrounding code.

Comment: Hi @user2357112 Do you think there's a way to get around it by simply removing those empty ones?

Comment: It's impossible for us to tell. If there's a bug in the code causing this comprehension to be run on inputs it shouldn't, though, you should fix that code rather than trying to patch up the results afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but more like an empty list within a list.

Assuming this is guaranteed you can do

```
# make sure value is not "[]" or "[[]]"
{k: v for k, v in complete_list.iteritems() if v and v[0]}
```

Example:

```
complete_list = {'x': [[]], 'y': [], 'z': [[1]]}
{k: v for k, v in complete_list.iteritems() if v and v[0]}
# returns {'z': [[1]]}
```

**EDIT**

From your updated question, I see you are zipping lists together after scraping from a website like so:

```
complete_dict=dict(zip(category_list,info_list))
```

It looks like your `info_list` is empty in some cases, just do

```
if info_list:
    complete_dict=dict(zip(category_list,info_list))
```

to ensure you don't zip `category_list` with an empty list.

Comment: sorry it doesn't seem like it's working. One thing is, I don't know what's being used as "key" when I zipped those two lists together. Both lists have empty entries, so there doesn't seem to have any problem zipping them together. However, since there's no "key" being used for empty values, I don't know how to call or remove those.

Comment: hmmm ok updated answer based on your edited question.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dict comprehension with an `is not None` check:

```
info_list = {k: v for (k, v) in complete_list.iteritems() if v is not None}
```

From the documentation on [dict comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Comment: I tried this, and the result is still the same. I used

'complete_dict2 = {k: v for k, v in complete_dict.iteritems() if v is not None}'

complete_dict is the dict after zipping the two lists together

Answer (score -1):

Use filter, you had it wrong, first argument must be callable accepting one argument, you can use built-in bool function

```
category_list = filter(bool, category_list)
```