# Remove Objects from python list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
a = [
    {
        "id" : 15,
        "name" : "abc"
    },
    {
        "id" : 16,
        "name" : "xyz"
    },
    {
        "id" : 17,
        "name" : "pqr"
    }
]

b = [15,17]
```

I have two lists as above, I want to remove the object from list a if its id is not present in list b. 
Any help, how to do that?

Output List:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 15,
        "name" : "abc"
    },
    {
        "id" : 17,
        "name" : "pqr"
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes it works, have accepted the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate in reverse gear for efficient, in-place deletion. Convert `b` into a `set` for constant time lookup.

```
c = set(b)    
for i in reversed(range(len(a))):  # thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga for this bit 
    if a[i]['id'] not in c:
        del a[i]
```

Otherwise, use a list comprehension and create it again:

```
a = [i for i in a if i['id'] in c]
```

```
print(a)
[{'id': 15, 'name': 'abc'}, {'id': 17, 'name': 'pqr'}]
```

Comment: I've come to prefer `reversed(range(len(a)))` instead of `range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Will commit that to memory! Very nifty.

Answer (score 0):

use list comprehention hence:

```
[i for i in a if i['id']!=b[0] and i['name']!=b[1]]
```

Comment: I think your answer is wrong because `b[0]`, `b[1]`, and `i['name']` are not relevant, and OP wants to keep those items whose `id`s are `in b`. So `[i for i in a if i['id'] in b]` might be what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```
a = [
     {
        "id" : 15,
        "name" : "abc"
    },
    {
        "id" : 16,
        "name" : "xyz"
    },
    {
        "id" : 17,
        "name" : "pqr"
    }]

b = [15, 17]

print [a[_] for _ in xrange(len(a)) if a[_]["id"] in b]
```

**output:**

```
[{'id': 15, 'name': 'abc'}, {'id': 17, 'name': 'pqr'}]
```