# Partial string match with str.contains using dict comprehension with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column called `course_names` with a mapping dictionary with a list of course names i'd like to match in the key and the value I would want to assign in the value column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'course_name' : ['Phsyics, Maths','Algebra & Maths','History','Geology','Biology']})


mapping = {'Algebra & Maths' : 'Mathematics',
'Phsyics' : 'Science',
'History' : 'History',
'Geology' : 'Geology',
'Biology' : 'Science'} 
# this goes on for about another 35 lines. 

#my attempt so far.

df['keys'] = [k for k, v in mapping.items() if df['course_name'] in k]
```

when I run this code I get :

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series
```

expected output :

```
    course_name          key
0   Phsyics, Maths      Science
1  Algebra & Maths  Mathematics
2          History      History
3          Geology      Geology
4          Biology      Science
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a small syntax error. You can also use `map`

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"course_name" : ["Algebra & Maths", "Phsyics"]})
Mapping = {'Algebra & Maths' : 'Mathematics','Phsyics' : 'Science'}
df["keys"] = [v for k, v in Mapping.items() if k in df['course_name'].tolist()]
#df["keys"] = df["course_name"].map(Mapping)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       course_name         keys
0  Algebra & Maths  Mathematics
1          Phsyics      Science
```

Comment: Thanks! this doesn't give me the required output in my post (was it unclear?) I need to match the course name to the key and return the value.

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: Thanks! I now get the error :  Length of values does not match length of index

do I need to apply pd.series ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? this just gives me a whole column of NaNs

Comment: `Length of values does not match length of index` This error is because there is a mismatch in the key - and value in DF["course_name"]

Comment: Understood, could .str.contains be used here as I'm after partial matches

Comment: Can you post a sample of your DF and the Mapping please?

Comment: Edited for you in the post, apologise I don't have my work laptop which had my code

Comment: @Datanovice. Can you also post the matching keys for the mentioned data please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170155/discussion-between-datanovice-and-rakesh).