# Putting inline condition on iteration in for loop

Tags: python

My current code looks like the following:

```
def my_func(target_user_id):
     for user_id in user_dictionary:
        if(user_id != target_user_id):
           #do something
```

Can I do something that looks like the following in python?

```
def my_func(target_user_id):
         for user_id != target_user_id in user_dictionary:
            #do something
```

So we can avoid a kind of obvious conditional block. I Appreciate your input.

Comment: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_fncs_map_filter_reduce.php this can probably help you as i think filter function will resolve your problem

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKlnR-CB3tk&t=491s

Comment: `for user_id in filter(lambda x: x != target_user_id, user_dictionary):` should do

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this is the correct answer. please raise it as an answer

Comment: It can be esier: `for user_id in (item for item in user_dictionary if item != target_user_id)`

Comment: as in one of the above comments, use filter function. Thats the most apt way for this scenario

Answer (score 4):

Your code is okay. If you're looking to avoid the test *in the loop* you have 2 options:

1) Looping on a generator comprehension could do the trick. It creates a second loop just for that...

```
for user_id in (x for x in user_dictionary if x != target_user_id):
```

2) It would be better to use `filter` to create a non-native python loop

```
for user_id in filter(lambda x: x != target_user_id, user_dictionary):
   ...
```

But it forces to create a `lambda`.

So all approaches would need to be timed with your data to pick the most efficient.

Comment: @L3viathan: ooops!! thanks a million for "filtering" it out :) too much copy/paste can kill you

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function), you could use something like:

```
def my_func(target_user_id):
         for user_id in {k: v for k, v in user_dictionary.iteritems() if k != target_user_id}:
            #do something
```

or if you are using python 3:

```
def my_func(target_user_id):
         for user_id in {k: v for k, v in user_dictionary.items() if k != target_user_id}:
            #do something
```

So your dictionary gets filtered before looping through so you don't need to check if the `user_id` is not the `target_user_id` in the actual loop.

Comment: it's not equivalent. Iterating on a dictionary iterates on the keys, your solution is filtering on the _values_.