# Python Dictionary search keys larger than

Tags: dictionary, search

I have a python dictionary with numerical keys.  I would like to find all the keys larger than the input key.  Similar to a list. 
Example of List:

```
for i in Mylist[10:]:
```

Here is example of my dictionary question:

```
dict = {133: "Value_1", 
    145: "Value_1",
    185: "Value_1",
    210: "Value_1",
    240: "Value_1",}

for i in dict[185:]:
```

Is something like this possible or can we search to only get the keys larger than 185?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

Answer (score 0):

That is not how dictionaries or lists work in python.
List values are accessed by their index number, not by the value itself.
Dictionary values are accessed by whatever the key for that value is.
So in your example, to find all keys greater than the input value, the code would look like this:

Get input and turning the input, which we assume will be a number, into an integer.

```
min_value = int(input('Enter the minimum key value to search for: '))
```

Add a list which we will append the appropriate values to.

```
valid_values = []
```

Iterate over keys in the dictionary, checking if it's higher than the given minimum value.

```
for key in dictionary:
    if key > min_value:
        valid_values.append(key)
```

And that's it. You have a list with all the values greater than the inputted number.

A more efficient way to do it would be to use list comprehension, like so:

```
valid_values = [key for key in dictionary if key > min_value]
```

In the list comprehension code, you are asking it to give you the key for every key in the dictionary if the key is greater than the minimum value, and then place it in the list which `valid_values` refers to.

Hope that helps!