# how to find the keys in dictionary by specifying upper and lower limit

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with co-ordinates as key values and the text in that position as values, as shown below.

```
dict={(310.96936089999997, 764.51895) : INTERNATIONAL UNION,
 (243.44624249999998, 510.79837879999997) : SULLIVAN & SON,
 (66.04973070000003, 430.55175) : DURATION}
```

I want to find and print only the key-values pairs that are in particular range say (200-550) should return SULLIVAN & SON.
Please let me know if there's a way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *dictionary comprehension* to keep only those keys with values within a range:

```
{i:d[i] for i in d if i[0]>200 and i[1]<550}
```

**Output**

```
{(243.44624249999998, 510.79837879999997): 'SULLIVAN & SON'}
```

Answer (score 1):

We love python : list-comprehension

```
def find_it(dict, *args)
    return {k:v for k,v in dict.items() if (
        args[0] > k[0] > args[1] and args[2] > k[1] > args[3]
    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
d={(310.96936089999997, 764.51895) : "INTERNATIONAL UNION",
 (243.44624249999998, 510.79837879999997) : "SULLIVAN & SON",
 (66.04973070000003, 430.55175) : "DURATION"}

result = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    if 200 < k[0] and k[1] < 550:
        print(v)
        result.update({k:v})
```

**Output:**

```
SULLIVAN & SON
```