# Json Dumps Select only keys with detected: true

Tags: python, json

I need some help with some Json serialisation. I need to print only the keys that have detected:true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop over your json objects and filter if detected == true.

For example:

```
import json

# This is your json data
input_json = """
[
  {
   ...
  }
]"""

# Load your json data and transform it to python objects
your_input_dict = json.loads(input_json)

# Filter the input dictionary
output = []
for x in your_input_dict:
  output = [obj for obj in x if x[obj]['detected'] == True]

print(output)
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers ==> output = [x for x in json.dumps(response) if x['detected'] == True]

Comment: Look at the edited code. This should work. It is important that you surround your json with a list.

Comment: i got the same error. Can you please try to put in in my entire code/?

Comment: I've edited the code again with your data. This should work now fine. The problem was that I didn't noticed that there were named objects in the object.

Comment: with print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

input_json = """
[
  {
   ...
  }
]"""

# Load your json data and transform it to python objects
your_input_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

# Filter the input dictionary
output = []
for x in your_input_dict:
  output = [obj for obj in x if x[obj]['detected'] == True]
print(output)
---synatx error on output = []

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function.

For example json is

```
example_json = [
   {
      "detected": True
   },
   {
      "detected": False
   }
]

list(filter(lambda x: (x["detected"] == True), example_json))
```

Comment: how can i put my print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4)) to your example_json? I am not able to link them. can you please edit your response so i can have the entire code? Thank you!

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers