# Filter key-value pairs in an ordered dictionary in python if keys differ from the first key by no more than x days

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, filter, key, difference

I have an ordered dictionary in python where keys are of format datetime and values are lists of items. I would like to be able to filter key-value pairs in this dictionary by the difference between a key and the first key. For example, I would like to only keep those key-value pairs that happened no later than 5 days after the first key-value pair did. In other words, if subtract 1st key value from another key value, the difference is 5 days or less.

I know I can filter a dictionary by a simple condition, as was done here:

[How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

But I'm not sure how to set up the condition in my case as I need to have an absolute reference to the first key and relative to every other key in the dictionary.

The dictionary I would like to filter looks like this:

```
my_dict = OrderedDict([
         (Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00'), ['a','b','c']),
         (Timestamp('2019-01-16 00:00:00'),['c', 'e', 'f', 'k']),
         (Timestamp('2019-01-23 00:00:00'), ['a', 'c', 'l']),
         (Timestamp('2019-02-08 00:00:00'), ['w','y','z'])
         ])
```

My filtered dictionary should only contain key-value pairs that have keys within 5 days from the first key, so I should end up with only first two key-value pairs.

```
filt_dict = OrderedDict([
         (Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00'), ['a','b','c']),
         (Timestamp('2019-01-16 00:00:00'),['c', 'e', 'f', 'k']),
         ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whats inside your `class Timestamp` so I made something that gets you started:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Timestamp:
    def __init__(self, t):
        t = datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.t = datetime(year=t.year, month=t.month, day=t.day, hour=t.hour, minute=t.minute, second=t.second)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.t < other.t

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.t - other.t

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.t)

my_dict = OrderedDict([
         (Timestamp('2019-01-11 00:00:00'), ['a','b','c']),
         (Timestamp('2019-01-16 00:00:00'),['c', 'e', 'f', 'k']),
         (Timestamp('2019-01-23 00:00:00'), ['a', 'c', 'l']),
         (Timestamp('2019-02-08 00:00:00'), ['w','y','z'])
         ])

first = [*my_dict.keys()][0]
d = timedelta(days=5)

new_dict = OrderedDict( (k, v) for k, v in my_dict.items() if k - first <= d )
print(new_dict)
```

Prints:

```
OrderedDict([(2019-01-11 00:00:00, ['a', 'b', 'c']), (2019-01-16 00:00:00, ['c', 'e', 'f', 'k'])])
```