# Matching multiple dictionary keys at a large scale in python

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

So, my program has a dictionary with values that change a lot.

```
example_dict = {'a': True, 'b' : "b", 'c' : "c", 'd' : "d", 'e' : False, 'f' : {'fa' : "", 'fb' : "b", 'fc' : "fc", "fd" : 0, "fe" : 0, "ff" : 0, "fg" : []}}
```

I have some if conditionals that need to check that a set of some of those keys (not all) match.

What works if I need to check several conditions is to use 'and'.

```
if example_dict['a'] == True and example_dict['b'] == "b" and example_dict['c'] == "c" or example_dict['a'] == False and example_dict['b'] == "bb" and example_dict['c'] == "c":
```

The above example would be checking the following, to see if they exist within the example dictionary:

```
{'a':True, 'b':"b", 'c':"c"}
{'a':False, 'b':"bb", 'c':"c"}
```

The problem is sometimes I need to check against 10+ sets of key values. It seems like there should be an easier way to do this, but I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function#16589453

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like it's checking the values based on their mathematical properties. I need exact strings, independent of each other. If that's applicable to my problem I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `all` iterator can be useful here.  Put your test conditions in an array and then use a list comprehension to get the result.

```
conditions = [('a', True), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 3)]
example_dict =  {'a': True, 'b': 'B', 'c': 3}
match = all(example_dict[k] == v for k, v in conditions)
```

EDIT: Add multiple condition sets

For checking sets of conditions, throw in an `any`.

```
# Declare sets of conditions to test
conditions = [[('a', True), ('b', 'B')],
              [('a', True), ('c', 3)],
              [('a', True), ('c', 34)]]

# An example dictionary to test
example_dict =  {'a': True, 'b': 'B', 'c': 3}

# Test if any of the condition sets match.  The any iterator will
# return True at the first matching set of conditions.  The all
# iterator will compare each key and value within a set of conditions.
match = any(all(example_dict[k] == v for k, v in c) for c in conditions)
```

Comment: No, `conditions` in the above is a list.  The `.items()` method only applies to dictionaries.

Comment: So... if I'm understanding the code at first glance, would I create an array for each set of conditions, then a list of the arrays, then do line 3 within a for loop?

Comment: Yes, you can put each set of conditions in a separate array, or use an array of arrays and iterate on each case.

Comment: Would you be able to add a couple of comment tags to your post explaining what it's actually doing? It would help me learn.

Comment: Added a more thorough example with comments.  For more details, check the `help` for the `any` and `all` built-in functions.

Comment: Thank you for the help, you really helped me to understand. I'm basically using this (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
def dict_agree(req, d):
    return all([v == d[k] for k, v in req.items()])


# Demonstration

example_dict = {'a': True, 'b' : "b", 'c' : "c", 'd' : "d", 'e' : False,
'f' : {'fa' : "", 'fb' : "b", 'fc' : "fc", "fd" : 0, "fe" : 0, "ff" : 0, "fg" : []}}

requirement_dict_1 = {'a': False, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
requirement_dict_2 = {'a': True, 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}

print(dict_agree(requirement_dict_1, example_dict)) # False, because 'a' has the wrong value
print(dict_agree(requirement_dict_1, example_dict)) # True, all the requirements are satisfied
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
cond =  {(True, 'b', 'c'), (False, 'bb', 'c')}
tuple(map(example_dict.get, ('a', 'b', 'c'))) in cond
```

this will be O(M) time complexity where M is  the number of keys that you want to inspect

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm answering my own question, because I'm implementing a hybrid of two, in case someone is reading this later. This is the code that appears to be working for me:

```
def main():
    # Dictionary to check
    example_dict = {'a': True, 'b' : "b", 'c' : "c", 'd' : "d", 'e' : False, 'f' : {'fa' : "", 'fb' : "b", 'fc' : "fc", "fd" : 0, "fe" : 0, "ff" : 0, "fg" : []}}
    # Conditions to find within the dictionary
    conditions = [[('a', True), ('b', "b"), ('c', "c")], [('a', False), ('b', "bb"), ('c', "c")]]
    # If the conditions aren't met, print false, else true
    if not check_conditions(example_dict, conditions):
        print("FALSE: a: {} b: {} c: {}".format(example_dict['a'], example_dict['b'], example_dict['c']))
    else:
        print("TRUE: a: {} b: {} c: {}".format(example_dict['a'], example_dict['b'], example_dict['c']))

# broken up into a function because my program
# is broken up over multiple files
def check_conditions(my_dict, condition_list):
    return any(all(my_dict[k] == v for k, v in c) for c in condition_list)
```

Output with dictionary as-is:

> TRUE: a: True b: b c: c

Output, when 'b' is replaced by 'bb' (doesn't meet 'b' condition in first, doesn't meet 'a' condition in second):

> FALSE: a: True b: bb c: c

The code uses tuples over dictionaries. My guess as to why the reason this works and the other way doesn't is because I think the code is checking to see if the whole dictionary matches, whereas tuples are isolating the specific keys.

Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Comment: I can't argue with that. I keep forgetting to choose something like 'd' when I'm making these examples.