# Getting all values from dictionary with specific key element

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, key

I have a dictionary in Python with 4 elements of the key (2 strings, 2 ints) and one numerical value. How do I return key-value pairs that have a specific value for one element of the key? For example, if my dictionary is `newdict`:

```py
newdict = {('1', '14', 3, 1): 3.469446951953614e-18,
     ('1', '14', 11, 1): 1.1102230246251565e-15,
     ('1', '17', 2, 1): 171.3624841,
     ('1', '21', 5, 1): -1.6764367671839864e-14,
     ('1', '21', 11, 1): 5.551115123125783e-17,
     ('1', '23', 8, 1): -4.163336342344337e-15,
     ('1', '24', 9, 1): -8.36136715420821e-15,
     ('1', '25', 5, 1): 0.0221293,
     ('1', '25', 9, 1): 0.0327717}
```

How would I return only the key-value pairs that have 5 as their third element, for example:

```py
{('1', '21', 5, 1): -1.6764367671839864e-14,
    ('1', '25', 5, 1): 0.0221293}
```

Comment: you can just iterate over the keys and return the ones matching your criteria, but this defeats the purpose of having a constant time access data structure)

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, your tuples can be sliced and indexed like lists, like `newdict[key][2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```py
{key: value for key, value in newdict.items() if key[2] == 5}
```

This outputs:

```py
{('1', '21', 5, 1): -1.6764367671839864e-14, ('1', '25', 5, 1): 0.0221293}
```

Comment: Here's a similar question that may also be helpful, as an addition to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function

Answer (score 0):

> How do I return key-value pairs that have a specific value for one element of the key?

- Write a function that takes position, value, and item parameters

  - Test the *key* portion of the item for the position and value
  - return a boolean for the test/comparison
- Filter the dictionary items using that function.