# Python dictionary filter certain part

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

i'm new to python and i got a problem with dictionary filter.
I searched a really long time for solution and asked on several discord server, but no one could really help me.

If i have a dictionary like this:

```
[
    {"champion": "ahri", "kills": 12, "assists": 7, "deaths": 4, "puuid": "17hd72he7wu"}
    {"champion": "sett", "kills": 14, "assists": 5, "deaths": 7, "puuid": "2123r3ze7wu"}
    {"champion": "thresh", "kills": 9, "assists": 16, "deaths": 2, "puuid": "32d72h5t5gu"}
]
```

How do i filter out only 1 certain part by puuid(value)? So it looks like this:

puuid = **"32d72h5t5gu"**

```
[
    {"champion": "thresh", "kills": 9, "assists": 16, "deaths": 2, "puuid": "32d72h5t5gu"}
]
```

with all other parts of dictionary **removed**.

Comment: You forgot many " double quotes, anyway I'm going to answer this soon, after editing the code in the question.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You have a list of dictionaries (not a dictionary) to start with. Do you want a list with all the "puuid" values? What code have you already written to get what you want? What result did it produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a list comprehension and cycle through the dictionaries in your list to only keep the one that meets the specified conditions.

```
[
{"champion": ahri, "kills": 12, "assists": 7, "deaths": 4, "puuid": 17hd72he7wu}
{"champion": sett, "kills": 14, "assists": 5, "deaths": 7, "puuid": 2123r3ze7wu}
{"champion": thresh, "kills": 9, "assists": 16, "deaths": 2, "puuid": 32d72h5t5gu}
]
```

```
newlist = [i for i in oldlist if (i['puuid'] == '32d72h5t5gu')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this:

new_list = [ x for x in orgininal_list if x[puuid] == value ]

its called a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

As the first thing, you should search for a question similar to yours.

- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension
- [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

This gives you half of the answer you're looking for: you can use a **`list` comprehension**.

```
dictionaries_list = [
    {"champion": "ahri", "kills": 12, "assists": 7, "deaths": 4, "puuid": "17hd72he7wu"}
    {"champion": "sett", "kills": 14, "assists": 5, "deaths": 7, "puuid": "2123r3ze7wu"}
    {"champion": "thresh", "kills": 9, "assists": 16, "deaths": 2, "puuid": "32d72h5t5gu"}
]

result = [d for d in dictionaries_list if d["puuid"] == "32d72h5t5gu"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = [
    {"champion": "ahri", "kills": 12, "assists": 7,
        "deaths": 4, "puuid": "17hd72he7wu"},
    {"champion": "sett", "kills": 14, "assists": 5,
        "deaths": 7, "puuid": "2123r3ze7wu"},
    {"champion": "thresh", "kills": 9, "assists": 16,
        "deaths": 2, "puuid": "32d72h5t5gu"}
]

new_list = [i for i in dictionary if (i['puuid'] == '32d72h5t5gu')]
```

[list Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp%5C)

Comment: link seem not working