# Count only alphabets in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, ascii

If I have a dictionary with keys of different characters, how can I only print the key: value pair where the key belongs to lowercase ASCII?

I have a code which prints out all characters using the counter method (i find the percentage of that character's occurrence):

Output:

o: 12.5 %

,: 3.571428571428571 %

l: 3.571428571428571 %

s: 3.571428571428571 %

So no comma would be desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [islower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) and [isascii()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isascii) builtins from python.

```
d = {'o': 12.5, ',': 3.57, 'l': 3.57, 's': 3.57}

for key in d:
    if key.islower() and key.isascii():
        print(f'{key}: {d[key]} %')
```

with Output:

```
o: 12.5 %
l: 3.57 %
s: 3.57 %
```