# A python program to filter dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, filter, integer

Write a python program to filter a dictionary based on values that are the multiples of 6
**NOTE:**

- Take keys as strings and values as integers.
  **Constraints:**
  1<=number of key value pairs<=10

`Sample test case: keys : a,b,c,d,e,f values:1,2,3,4,5,6 {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6} {'f':6}`

Comment: Go for it!  Let us know if you have any problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a dictionary according to an arbitrary condition function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844516/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-according-to-an-arbitrary-condition-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension.

```py
d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6}
res = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v % 6 == 0}
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
old_dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6}

#or this it will work totally perfect

#old_dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13}

print (f"Original dictionary is : {old_dict}")

print()

new_dict = {key:value for (key, value) in old_dict.items() if value % 6 == 0}

print(f"New dictionary with multiple of 6 is : {new_dict}")
```